# How to avoid auto reset of npmrc?

Tags: node.js, npm

OS: UBUNTU 16
npm version: 6.4.1
My proxy settings in ~/.npmrc file keep getting reset with opening a new terminal? I am behind a corporate proxy, so I set the proxy in ~/.npmrc. But with a new terminal, it keeps changing to some fixed proxy setting. I checked the global config npmrc and it is empty. Any way I can make the config not change with opening a new terminal?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked in your .bashrc or .bash_profile to see if anything is doing that?

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I thought I looked into bashrc but missed npm references there.

Comment: glad you found it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Luke! My bashrc had npm proxy setting statements that was overwriting npmrc proxy config. This is resolved now.